# Leaflet js problem with tileLayer and control

Tags: leaflet

I have a Leaflet map with a control with openstreetmap and googlemap, when I load my page I see a openstreetmap for a istance and then swich to googlemap but I want to show openstreetmap for default.

this is my code:

```
<script>
var openStreetMap = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    });

    var googleMap = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
        maxZoom: 20,
        subdomains: ['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2', 'mt3']
    });


    var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [43.44084,11.8602],
        zoom: 13,
        layers: [openStreetMap, googleMap]
    });
    



    var baseMaps = {
        'openStreetMap': openStreetMap,
        'googleMap': googleMap
    };

    L.control.layers(baseMaps).addTo(map);

    map.spin(true);

$.getJSON("http://localhost/fit-file-analysis-2/geojson.php",function(data){
   
    

    L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
    map.spin(false);
});
```

Comment: Add the desired tilelayer to the map, i.e. `.addTo(map)`.

Answer (score 1):

You add an object of `baseMaps` to your `map` but you didn’t affect a tile layer.

Like @IvanSanchez says, you must add the tile layer to your map:

```
openStreetMap.addTo(map);
```